nx.dev next.config.js: Unexpected token 'export'
How import other libary in next.config.js in nx.dev monorepo?
i have error on nx dev project-app:
Failed to process project graph. Run "nx reset" to fix this. Please report the issue if you keep seeing it. See errors below.

Failed to process project graph. Run "nx reset" to fix this. Please report the issue if you keep seeing it.
  AggregateCreateNodesError: An error occurred while processing files for the @nx/next/plugin plugin.
    - apps/project-app/next.config.js: Unexpected token 'export'

I create empty next.js template and create default js lib with nx.dev
app/project-app/next.config.js
//@ts-check

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const { composePlugins, withNx } = require('@nx/next');
const {mylib} = require('@project/mylib');

console.log(mylib())

/**
 * @type {import('@nx/next/plugins/with-nx').WithNxOptions}
 **/
const nextConfig = {
  nx: {
    // Set this to true if you would like to use SVGR
    // See: https://github.com/gregberge/svgr
    svgr: false,
  },
};

const plugins = [
  // Add more Next.js plugins to this list if needed.
  withNx,
];

module.exports = composePlugins(...plugins)(nextConfig);

mylib/src/index.ts
export function mylib(): string {
  return 'mylib';
}


const composePluginsConfig = composePlugins(...plugins)(nextConfig);
module.exports = composePluginsConfig

Try with above syntax
